# How to wait on all tasks (created task and subtask) without using TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, thread-synchronization

I will have to create a concurrent software which create several Task, and every Task could generate another task(that could also generate another Task, ...).

I need that the call to the method which launch task is blocking: no return BEFORE all task and subtask are completed.

I know there is this `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` property, but I think it will not fit:

The server will have something like 8 cores at least, and each task will create 2-3 subtask, so if I set the `AttachedToParent` option, I've the impression that the second sub-task will not start before the three tasks of the first subtask ends. So I will have a limited multitasking here.

So with this process tree:

[image]

I've the impression that if I set AttachedToParent property everytime I launch a thread, B will not ends before E,F,G are finished, so C will start before B finish, and I will have only 3 actives thread instead of the 8 I can have.

If I don't put the AttachedToParent property, A will be finished very fast and return.

So how could I do to ensure that I've always my 8 cores fully used if I don't set this option?

Comment: Don't rely on impressions. Either look it up in the documentation or try it out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` does not prevent the other subtasks from starting, but rather prevents the parent task itself from closing. So when E,F and G are started with AttachedToParent, B is not flagged as finished until all three are finished. So it should do just as you want.

The [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/6e142b15-0e41-4cbc-bccc-bb7bdebe0795/) (in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

As Me.Name mentioned, `AttachedToParent` doesn't behave according to your impressions. I think it's a fine option in this case.

But if you don't want to use that for whatever reason, you can wait for all the child tasks to finish with [`Task.WaitAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx). Although it means you have to have all of them in a collection.

`Task.WaitAll()` blocks the current thread until all the `Task`s are finished. If you don't want that and you are on .Net 4.5, you can use [`Task.WhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139093%28v=vs.110%29), which will return a single `Task` that will finish when all of the given `Task`s finish.

Answer (score 1):

You could you `TaskFactory` create options like in this example:

```
Task parent = new Task(() => { 
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(); 
var tf = new TaskFactory<Int32>(cts.Token,  
                                        TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent,  
                                        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,  
TaskScheduler.Default); 

 // This tasks creates and starts 3 child tasks 
 var childTasks = new[] { 
       tf.StartNew(() => Sum(cts.Token, 10000)), 
       tf.StartNew(() => Sum(cts.Token, 20000)), 
       tf.StartNew(() => Sum(cts.Token, Int32.MaxValue))  // Too big, throws Overflow
 }; 

// If any of the child tasks throw, cancel the rest of them 
for (Int32 task = 0; task <childTasks.Length; task++) 
  childTasks[task].ContinueWith( 
     t => cts.Cancel(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted); 

// When all children are done, get the maximum value returned from the  
// non-faulting/canceled tasks. Then pass the maximum value to another  
// task which displays the maximum result 
tf.ContinueWhenAll( 
   childTasks,  
   completedTasks => completedTasks.Where( 
     t => !t.IsFaulted && !t.IsCanceled).Max(t => t.Result), CancellationToken.None) 
   .ContinueWith(t =>Console.WriteLine("The maximum is: " + t.Result), 
      TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously); 
}); 

// When the children are done, show any unhandled exceptions too 
parent.ContinueWith(p => { 
    // I put all this text in a StringBuilder and call Console.WriteLine just once  
    // because this task could execute concurrently with the task above & I don't  
    // want the tasks' output interspersed 
    StringBuildersb = new StringBuilder( 
                      "The following exception(s) occurred:" + Environment.NewLine); 

    foreach (var e in p.Exception.Flatten().InnerExceptions)  
         sb.AppendLine("   "+ e.GetType().ToString()); 

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); 
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

  // Start the parent Task so it can start its children 
  parent.Start();
```